# Cannot instantiate Map<String, ? extends Object> map = new TreeMap<String, ? extends Object>();

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, treemap

I am trying to create a `TreeMap` with a generic type but I am unable to. I am doing this because my map can like these:

```
 Map<String, QueryTerm> terms = new TreeMap<String, QueryTerm>();        
    Map<String, String> params = new TreeMap<String, String>();
```

So instead of creating multiple functions to handle the maps with different types I want to create one which both types.

How can I do this and what am I doing wrong?

**Function**:

```
 private Map<String, ? extends Object> setDatumMap(UserSession session, String parameterName)

    {
        Map<String, ? extends Object> map = new TreeMap<String, ? extends Object>();            

        //Get comma delimited list of filter keys. Split them and use them to retrieve associated values.  
    String sFilters = (String) session.getAttribute(parameterName);
    String[] filterList = sFilters.split(",");
    for(String filterName : filterList)
    {
        String filterValue = (String) session.getAttribute(filterName);
        if (filterValue != null && !filterValue.isEmpty())
        {
            filter.put(filterName, setQueryTermList(filterValue, ListType.BOOLEAN_LIST));
        }
    }
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: Post the function as you have tried to write it so far...

Comment: Take advantage of Java SE 7 `Map<String, QueryTerm> terms = new TreeMap<>();`. Also, you have some serious code flaws there.

Answer (score 4):

You should simply instantiate the map like so:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
```

You can't instantiate using a wildcard, and it's not necessary unless you expect that the compiler will cast to the appropriate class by guessing what value you are going to get. We didn't get there yet.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change you this line :

```
private Map<String, ? extends Object> setDatumMap(UserSession session, String parameterName)
{
    Map<String, ? extends Object> map = new TreeMap<String, ? extends Object>();  
     //rest of your code
```

To

```
private Map<String, Object> setDatumMap(UserSession session, String parameterName)
{
    Map<String, Object> map = new TreeMap<String, Object>(); 
    //rest of your code.
```

This will work.